# Are there other known public security sections other than Section 9?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

We're all aware of Public Security Section 9, its operatives and scope.

The question is: are there other known sections, and if so, what are their scopes/mandates?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there are other sections, first mentioned in the first movie.

**Section 1**
Also known as the *Special Service Squad*, it acts like a special police unit (compare: SWAT)

**Section 2**

> Section 2 is under the control of the Ministry of Health, Labour and Welfare, in charge of conducting law enforcement matters regarding unauthorized experiments and patents take place without the Ministry of Health, Labour and Welfare's consent.

**Section 3**
Enforces the anti-drug operations in Japan.

**Section 4**
A special unit in the *Japanese Ground Self Defence Forces*, also known as "The Rangers".

**Section 6**

> Section 6 is an Intelligence, Surveillance and Reconnaissance unit under jurisdiction of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs known as the Treaty Council.

Qoutes are from the [Ghost In The Shell-Wikia](http://ghostintheshell.wikia.com/wiki/Organizations).

Answer (score 0):

#### Section 1

Also known as "Special Service Squad". This section investigates very serious crimes, and its reach is limited to Japan only.

#### Section 2

Enforces law in the area of biomedical experiments (un)authorized by Ministry of Health, Labour and Welfare. Also enforces patents.

#### Section 3

Works the drug-related crimes in Japan.

#### Section 4

Special forces unit called "The Rangers". Batou is an ex-ranger and has cyberized eyes like the rest of his former colleagues, as seen in GITS:SAC.

#### Section 6

Surveillance and Reconnaissance unit. They are not very cyberized and they don't see much action.

Source is [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ghost_in_the_Shell#Public_Security_Bureaus) plus my own recollection of the events. It is currently unknown what sections 5, 7 and 8 do.